# How to add different placeholder color

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

> ::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* WebKit, Blink, Edge */
> color:    #909; }
>
> This code change color of all input placeholder. How to make different placeholder colors for different input fields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to be more specified:

if you put `::-webkit-input-placeholder` in the CSS, you will select all placeholders... but this is not what we want

so using `:nth-of-type();` a pseudo-class, you can select the wanted one, easily.

useful documentations:

- [`nth-of-type` MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type)

so the code will be like this:

```css
/* 1 */

input:nth-of-type(1)::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: green;
}


/* 2 */

input:nth-of-type(2)::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: blue;
}


/* 3 */

input:nth-of-type(3)::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<!-- 1 -->
<input type="text" name="" id="" placeholder="hello world">
<!-- 2 -->
<input type="text" name="" id="" placeholder="hello world">
<!-- 3 -->
<input type="text" name="" id="" placeholder="hello world">
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use `::placeholder` to style the `placeholder`.

> The ::placeholder CSS pseudo-element represents the placeholder text in an  or  element.

Notice that Internet Explorer doesn't support this, but since you are using `webkit`, you are using Chrome or Safari, this will work for you.

Example:

```css
::placeholder{
color:red;
opacity:0.6

}
```

```html
<input placeholder='yes'/>
```